# Views and search_path

Tags: postgresql

My Postgres database is a multi-schema one. 
Each schema got the same structures but the data are differents.

It was working fine since i encountered a specific problem.
It seems that views are generated based on the current search_path.

Let's say my database is like :

- public
- schema1

If i `SET search_path TO schema1, public`.
Then `SELECT * FROM schema1.view;`
It will retrieve the data from the public schema.

I tried to change the search_path before generating my view, it didn't work.
I tried to prefix my tables into my view, it worked. My solution is to prefix with the target schema before creating my views with my 'new database' script. But i find it a bit 'dirty';

I'd love to have more insight on the subject !

Thanks

Comment: You need to post the full code, otherwise this is impossible to answer. Maybe the view simply retrieves data from the _tables_ in the public schema? Please [edit] your question and add the `create table` and `create view` statements for the tables in question. [**Formatted text**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 5):

When a view is created, all unqualified object names in the view definition are resolved according to the value of `search_path` *at the time the view is created*. The Object-ID of the referenced tables is part of the view definition.

So it does not matter what `search_path` is set to when you `SELECT` from the view.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So logically, if i set my `searth_path` before creating the view it should be ok ? I'll test that right away

Comment: Edit : it didn't work
I tried 
`set search_path to schema1;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW schema1.invoice AS 
 SELECT invoice.id
 FROM invoice;
 
ALTER TABLE schema1.invoice
  OWNER TO mainrole;`

It still querying from the public schema and not from schema1.

Comment: Then you must have made a mistake somewhere. Perhaps there are two views with the same name in different schemas and you query the wrong one? Try `BEGIN; SET LOCAL search_path=pg_catalog; SELECT pg_get_viewdef('schema1.invoice'::regclass); COMMIT;` to see which table is used in the view.